# VS2019 and _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE, how to explain this weirdo?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, cl

Please check my short code below.

pwrapper.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

extern"C" int mm_printfA(const char *fmt, ...);
extern"C" int mm_printfW(const wchar_t *fmt, ...);
```

pwrapper.cpp

```
#include "pwrapper.h"

int mm_printfA(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    int ret = vprintf(fmt, args);

    va_end(args);
    return ret;
}

int mm_printfW(const wchar_t *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    
    int ret = vwprintf(fmt, args);
    
    va_end(args);
    return ret;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "pwrapper.h"

// cl /MT /D _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE main.cpp pwrapper.cpp

void main()
{
    mm_printfA("What is %d?\n", 123);
}

#if 0
void usedull()
{
    vprintf(NULL, NULL);
    vwprintf(NULL, NULL);
}
#endif
```

For some reason, I need to compile it with `_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE`, like this:

```
cl /MT /D _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE main.cpp pwrapper.cpp
```

But link stage fails saying unresolved external symbol `vwprintf` and `vprintf` .

[image]

A very weird workaround I find out is: **Enable the `usedull()` function body** -- although never be called, and, link through `pwrapper.lib`, using bb.bat below:

```
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@set CFLAGS=/D _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE

cl /nologo /c /MT %CFLAGS% pwrapper.cpp
@if errorlevel 1 exit /b 4

lib /nologo  /out:pwrapper.lib pwrapper.obj
@if errorlevel 1 exit /b 4

cl /nologo /c /MT  main.cpp
@if errorlevel 1 exit /b 4

link /nologo main.obj pwrapper.lib
@if errorlevel 1 exit /b 4
```

Well, this really works, but why?

[image]

This is not a pleasant workaround, because each exe project needs to include a "useless" `usedull()` function. So, is there any better way?

I really can't tell why this workaround works, an explanation of it is very welcome.

### ==== Some Clarification ====

There were two `main.cpp` in my original post. Let me name them separately for later reference in case someone would bother to answer this weird question.

- `main.0.cpp` refers to the one without `usedull()`.
- `main.1.cpp` refers to the one with `usedull()`.

In this question, I use VC++ headers and libs for application(not for kernel), and

- I compile `main.0.cpp` and `main.1.cpp` without `_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE`.
- I always compile pwrapper.cpp **with** `_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE`.

Whether having pwrapper.obj go through pwrapper.lib produce the same result in this issue.

Comment: I'd first attempt to determine why you need to define `_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE`. It's not needed for the example you've provided here, as `cl /MT main.cpp pwrapper.cpp` builds without issue.

Comment: Well, it happened when I was coding a KMDF driver. I accidentally linked my self-compiled user-mode mm_snprintf.lib to the final kernel-mode .sys and that weird behavior happened, and the resulting .sys works. Finally, I recompiled mm_snprintf with kernel-mode header and linked it to .sys, and the problem is ultimately gone. Yes, `_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE` tweaking is not required.  I keep the question here to record the mystical `usedull()` behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

- compiling `pwrapper.cpp` with `-D _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE` tells the compiler you are going to provide your own implementation of `vprintf` and `vwprintf` at link time, and
- compiling `main.cpp` *without* `-D _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE` tells the compiler to include implementations of `vprintf` and `vwprintf` which are used at link time to satisfy both the references from `usedull` and `mm_printfA`/`mm_printfW`

so, this particular combination works to resolve all undefined symbols at link time. See below for more discussion however.

#### Discussion

In `stdio.h`, `vprintf` (which I'll focus on, but `vwprintf` is configured in the same way) is defined like so:

```
_Check_return_opt_
_CRT_STDIO_INLINE int __CRTDECL vprintf(
    _In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ char const* const _Format,
                                  va_list           _ArgList
    )
#if defined _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE
;
#else
{
    return _vfprintf_l(stdout, _Format, NULL, _ArgList);
}
#endif
```

Note that

- if `_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE` is defined, this becomes a forward declaration
- whereas if it is not defined, the full body is included in the compilation of the including [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29).

Additionally, in `corecrt_stdio_config.h` whether `_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE` is defined determines the value of `_CRT_STDIO_INLINE`; if it is defined, `_CRT_STDIO_INLINE` is defined as empty, otherwise it is defined as `__inline`.

Putting these together,

- if `_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE` is not defined, these functions will be candidates for [inline expansion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?view=msvc-170#inline-__inline-and-__forceinline),
- otherwise a separate implementation of that function will need to be provided at link time.

#### Default Compilation (no `/O1`, `/O2`, no `_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE`)

The above works with the specific compile and link invocations you are using, as without optimization the compiler will simply include the function body in the compilation of `main.1.obj`. You can see this using [`dumpbin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-command-line?view=msvc-170); running `dumpbin -symbols main.1.obj | find "| vprintf"` prints:

```
01D 00000000 SECT8  notype ()    External     | vprintf
```

showing that `main.1.obj` provides `vprintf` as an externally available symbol.

Checking `pwrapper.obj`, we get:

```
00A 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | vprintf
```

showing that `vprintf` is undefined in this object file, and will need to be provided at link time.

#### Optimisation for Inline Expansion

However, if we change the [optimisation option for inline expansion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ob-inline-function-expansion?view=msvc-170), we get different results. Using even the first level of optimisation (`-Ob1`, included in `-O1` and `-O2`) like so:

```
cl -c -Ob1 main.1.cpp
```

causes the compiler to incorporate the body of `vprintf` directly into `usedull`, and remove the separate implementation of `vprintf`, which can be confirmed using `dumpbin`. So, as you would now expect, attempting to link `main.1.obj` and `pwrapper.obj` together will once again give your original error:

```
pwrapper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol vwprintf referenced in function mm_printfW
pwrapper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol vprintf referenced in function mm_printfA
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

#### Multiple Implementations?

So, following on from that it is apparent that compiling both files with `-D _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE` will fail as there will be no implementations of the relevant methods. What about if both are compiled *without* this definition?

If we check the object files, both have defined symbols for `vprintf`:

```
01D 00000000 SECT8  notype ()    External     | vprintf
```

and:

```
01A 00000000 SECT7  notype ()    External     | vprintf
```

which under normal circumstances would result in errors due both to [multiple definitions of a symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1169?view=msvc-170) and violations of the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). However, when performing inline expansion, the compiler and linker have your back. As per [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?view=msvc-170#inline-__inline-and-__forceinline):

> Rather than expand an inline function defined in a header file, the compiler may create it as a callable function in more than one translation unit. The compiler marks the generated function for the linker to prevent one-definition-rule (ODR) violations.

Comment: Thank you for point out, the problem is rooted from `__inline` behavior.